# Vocabularies about order of the things

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

I want to know if what certain orders or positions in the orders are in English.

The following are my questions, assume that we have ten apples, I put my questions on these apples:

What is the name of the order when all apples are red? We say the apples are all red?

What is the name of the order when one apple (the first) is red, the next one is yellow, and then the third one is red and the forth one is yellow again and this continues to the last apple.

What is the name of the order when one is red, and the next two are yellow and the forth one is red and again the next two are yellow and ....

You see, I'm seeking for word/phrase to describe this orders.

My second concern is the position of the items in an order.

We say the first apple is red.
We say the last apple is red.
But, how do we say one apple to the end is red? I mean an apple before the last one?

Thanks

Comment: "All the apples are red", "the apples alternate in a red/yellow pattern", The apples cycle through a pattern of red/yellow/yellow", "The next to the last apple is red". These are just suggestions, I am sure there are lots of ways of saying them. Do you have expressions for these in your native language?

Comment: Yes we have. And I have snapped some in English. But my mind does not afford remembering them now...

Comment: What are they in yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "order" you mean the arrangement or organization, you can try these terms directly or look them up in a thesaurus for some alternatives:

> What is the name of the order when all apples are red? We say the apples are all red?

**Uniform pattern** *The apples are uniformly red.*

> What is the name of the order when one apple (the first) is red, the next one is yellow, and then the third one is red and the forth one is yellow again and this continues to the last apple.

**Alternating pattern** *The apples alternate between two colors - red and yellow.*

> What is the name of the order when one is red, and the next two are yellow and the forth one is red and again the next two are yellow and ....

**Repeating pattern** *The apples have a pattern that repeats after every three.*

> We say the first apple is red.

**First item** is red.

> We say the last apple is red.

**Last Item** is red, **Ultimate item** is red.

> But, how do we say one apple to the end is red? I mean an apple before the last one?

**Next-to-last item** is red, **Penultimate item** is red.